# Magento fill editbox on exit

Tags: ajax, magento, jquery, magento-1.7

This should be pretty straightforward question but can't find how to do it. On the frontend I have a form with some edit boxes or `input-text` fields. In one of them the user will write/paste a blog url. When the user exits the box I want to:

1. grab this url and parse/search/get from that blog the tags related to the [OpenGraph protocol](http://ogp.me/) if they exists. If there are no tags of this kind then the usual `title` and related tags will be used.
2. <strike>then use the values of the tags to fill other edit fields on the current form, title, comments, description, image, etc</strike>

How can these actions can be accomplished, **AJAX** maybe? Together with **jQuery**? Or some other solution?
For now I have searched and here are some of the links I guess could be useful:

- [Need to display user's choices realtime in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391049/need-to-display-users-choices-realtime-in-magento)
- [Using Basic AJAX calls within Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835146/using-basic-ajax-calls-within-magento)
- [Magento and AJAX.Updater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713794/magento-and-ajax-updater)
- [Refreshing DIV content with AJAX](http://www.aleixcortadellas.com/main/2009/02/11/232/)

I have a fully working module, with several different models, layouts, controllers, backend administration, several frontend functionalities, etc. But on this case I don't even know exactly where to start, wich files to modify and what to add on the form on the first place.

**EDIT**

Managed to accomplish second point, to fill other input files using the answer from the Ajax request using `XMLHttpRequest`. Here are the different files, just in case someone has a different solution or some recommendation. Not showing all the code as it would be too long.

phtml file:

```
<div id="blog_link_block">
    <input class="input-text required-entry" onchange="showHint(this.value)"
            name="blog_link" id="blog_link_field" type="text"  style="width: 210px;"
            value="" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="title_field"><?php echo $this->__('Title'); ?>
        <span class="required">*</span>
    </label><br />
    <input class="input-text required-entry" name="title" id="title_field" type="text"
           style="width: 450px;" value="" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showHint(str)
    {
        <?php $block = Mage::getBlockSingleton('blogtest/product_view');
        $temp = $block->getUrl('blogtest/blogtagsajax/index');?>

        if (str.length==0)
        { 
            document.getElementById("title_field").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("title_field").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo $temp ?>?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <blogtest_blogtagsajax_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <remove name="root"/>
        </reference>
        <block type="blogtest/product_ajax" name="product.ajax" output="toHtml" />
    </blogtest_blogtagsajax_index>
</layout>
```

Controller:

```
<?php
class Dts_Blogtest_BlogtagsajaxController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

php file to handle the request:

```
<?php
class Dts_Blogtest_Block_Product_Ajax extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {

    public function __construct(){
        echo self::myFunc();
    }

    public function myFunc() {
        $a[]="Anna";
        $a[]="Brittany";
        $a[]="Cinderella";
        $a[]="Diana";

        //get the q parameter from URL
        $q=$_GET["q"];

        //lookup all hints from array if length of q>0
        if (strlen($q) > 0)
        {
            $hint="";
            for($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++){
                if (strtolower($q)==strtolower(substr($a[$i],0,strlen($q)))){
                    if ($hint==""){
                        $hint=$a[$i];
                    }
                    else{
                        $hint=$hint." , ".$a[$i];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if ($hint == ""){
            $response="no suggestion";
        }
        else{
            $response=$hint;
        }

        //output the response
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer point number one tried using [OpenGraphNode](http://buzzword.org.uk/2010/opengraph/#php) library but get stuck [with some errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972049/php-and-opengraph-protocol-errors).

Then I found this [question/answer right here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711357/get-title-and-meta-tags-of-external-site) and all problems gone. The propossed function on the accepted answer is working flawlessly with the `og:` tags. Here is my modified version:

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
}

public function myFunc() {
    // get the q parameter from URL
    $q = $_GET["q"];

    $html = self::file_get_contents_curl($q);

    //parsing begins here:
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);
    $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
    $title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

    for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++){
        $meta = $metas->item($i);
        if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'og:title')
            $title = $meta->getAttribute('content');
        if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'og:description')
            $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
        if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'keywords')
            $keywords = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    }

    $title = trim($title);
    if ($title  == ""){
        $response = "no title";
    }
    else{
        $response = $title;
    }
    //output the response
    return $response;
}
```